# How to merge data in elasticsearch

Tags: php, arrays, elasticsearch, merge, array-merge

i want to merge some data in Elasticsearch, but every time it is replacing my previous data and not merging it.

Suppose when i new is created it should add with the previous data, not replacing previous data. So Suppose there is a user exists in the "update_field" named "Christofer" so when i array_merge($usernames) where $usernames contains one or couple of usernames it is always replacing previous data.

I am working on PHP.

```
        $usernames= array ("Johanna", "Maria");
        $doc = array();
        $doc['update_field'] = array_merge($usernames);

        $u_params = array();
        $u_params['id'] = 'my_id';
        $u_params['index'] = 'my_index';
        $u_params['type'] = 'my_type';

        $u_params['body'] = array('doc' => $doc);

        $client->update($u_params);
```

For being more clear, as a example let's say in the usernames field there are couple of username exists- like - "Christofer", "Henrik", "Eric".

So now i want to add more user like - "Johanna", "Maria", ...

Now every time i merge and update documents it is replacing the data, like ("Christofer", "Henrik", "Eric") is getting replace by ("Johanna", "Maria").

I want them to be added not replaced.

Do any body knows how can i merge the new data, or just the new data in other process. Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [partial update](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/php-api/2.0/_updating_documents.html#_partial_document_update). Try this instead, i.e. you need to send a `doc` hash in the body with the fields to marge (i.e. `update_fields`):

```
$params = [
    'index' => 'my_index',
    'type' => 'my_type',
    'id' => 'my_id',
    'body' => [
        'doc' => [
            'update_field' => array_merge($usernames)
        ]
    ]
];
$client->update($params);
```

**UPDATE**

That's right, core values and arrays are getting replaced.
You may want to try [scripted partial update](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/php-api/2.0/_updating_documents.html#_scripted_document_update) then

```
    $usernames= array ("Johanna", "Maria");
    $script = array();
    $script['script'] = 'ctx._source.update_field += new_value';
    $script['params'] = array('new_value' => array_merge($usernames));

    $u_params = array();
    $u_params['id'] = 'my_id';
    $u_params['index'] = 'my_index';
    $u_params['type'] = 'my_type';

    $u_params['body'] = $script;

    $client->update($u_params);
```

And make sure that scripting is enabled in your `elasticsearch.yml` config file:

```
script.disable_dynamic: false
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, but actually i have tried that before, but it is not working for me, i have update my question to be more clear, can you kindly look one more time please :) thanks

Comment: thanks a lot for your great answer, although it is returning this error ----{"error":"RemoteTransportException[[Fin][inet[/192.168.1.127:9300]][indices:data/write/update]]; nested: ElasticsearchIllegalArgumentException[failed to execute script]; nested: ScriptException[scripts of type [inline], operation [update] and lang [groovy] are disabled]; ","status":400}

Comment: Ok, yes, scripting needs to be enabled, my bad. What ES version are you using by the way?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your great answer :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84684/discussion-between-christofer-hansen-and-val).